# hg extdiff -p and %~dp0

Tags: mercurial, batch-file, cmd

`myprogram.cmd` is in PATH;

`myprogram.cmd` uses `%~dp0` to determine the folder it is in;

I have included `@echo %~dp0` into `myprogram.cmd` for debugging;

When I call `myprogram.cmd` from anywhere, it works perfectly, displaying the folder `myprogram.cmd` is in;

When I call `hg extdiff -p myprogram.cmd`, it does not work, displaying something like `c:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\extdiff.3n8op2\`.

Here is the related part of `hgrc` file:

```
[extensions]
hgext.extdiff =
```

What do I do wrong? Should not `%~dp0` return drive and path of the batch file? What do I use instead? Do I have to apply some special configuration to Mercurial repository? Passing the full path of `myprogram.cmd` to `hg extdiff -p` is not an option, unless it is done automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using %~dp$PATH:0, but you need to always specify the extension. For example, for the following `test.cmd`:

```
rem test.cmd
@echo dp0 == %~dp0
@echo dp$PATH:0 == %~dp$PATH:0
```

these are two sample runs from the `d:\hg` folder:

```
$ hg extdiff -p test.cmd
dp0 == c:\Users\estefan\AppData\Local\Temp\extdiff.pamj6n\
dp$PATH:0 == k:\home\Scripts\

$ hg extdiff -p test
dp0 == c:\Users\estefan\AppData\Local\Temp\extdiff.dgp0qz\
dp$PATH:0 ==
```

From http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html:

> %~$PATH:1 Search the PATH environment variable and expand %1 to the fully qualified name of the first match found.

Answer (score 2):

The %~dp0 trick is **a big lie**. It is not actually a magic variable, it's simply a manipulation of %0 (or whichever var you stick the ~dp in front of). It simply takes whatever **string** is in that variable and tells you what its drive and path components appear to be. If that string is simply a name like "myprogram", it says "well, filenames without drives and paths are assumed to be in the current directory".

So the %~dp0 trick only works if either:

a) you've launched your script by its full name or
b) you happen to be in the directory where it resides

In this case, you run:

```
hg extdiff -p myprogram
```

gets turned into the following call to Windows:

```
CreateProcess(NULL, "cmd.exe /c myprogram some diff args", ..., "c:/some/temp/path", ...)
```

which is morally equivalent to opening a shell and running:

```
C:\>cd c:\some\temp\path
C:\some\temp\path>myprogram some diff args
%0 is myprogram
%~dp0 is C:\some\temp\path
```

I recommend passing the full program name for your tool like this via your .hgrc:

```
[extdiff]
myprogram=c:/tools/myprogram.cmd
```

But be warned, this can get confused by the presence of spaces in your filename, you may need to experiment with quoting.

Comment: Possibly you missed this bit of the original post: *‘When I call `myprogram.cmd` from anywhere, **it works perfectly**, displaying the folder `myprogram.cmd` is in’*.

Comment: No, I just chose to ignore it because it's counterfactual according to both documentation and testing, both with and without Mercurial.

Comment: @mpm, how would you explain that %~dp0 finds the path when I launch the script without its fullname from another directory (assuming it is in PATH)? It is more elaborate than you explain: when %0 is just `myprogram.cmd`, %~dp0 still can detect the path to it, if `myprogram.cmd` was launched from cmd.

Comment: I suppose it's remotely possible that some versions of Windows have a special case for when you expand the %0 string... but since that special case clearly isn't getting invoked in your problem above (and isn't documented to), I strongly suggest you stop relying on this magic.